# Did windows 10 2004 eliminate the trailing slash on a tab completion of a directory, and is there a way to get it back?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I just updated to the Windows 10 2004 update, and I noticed right away that Powershell was behaving differently.  Opening up a new powershell window at c:\ and typing

```
cd us<TAB>
```

With tab completion used to give me:

> cd .\Users\

But now it generates:

> cd .\Users

Without the trailing slash, meaning that directory navigation takes more keystrokes.  I'm assuming that this is something that came in the latest update-has anyone found a way to revert this behaviour?  Seems to be the same in standard powershell (via win+x) or windows Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I feel kind of dumb for missing this, but in my defense, I'd gotten so used to tuning out the "try PS core" header that I just ignore everything before the prompt.  Anyway, I noticed there was a warning on launching powershell: "Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes."...

Re-importing PSReadLine fixed the issue.  To fix permanently, I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014754/cause-of-warning-powershell-detected-that-you-might-be-using-a-screen-reader-an) question that suggested setting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access\On to 0, which worked.

Adding answer in case others stumble across the same issue.  No idea why it thought I was using a screen reader after the upgrade, but things are back to normal.